# Get last value of BehaviorSubject after it's completed

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to create a latch which will indicate if something "is ready".
It needs to hold a state which I can access after the observable completes.

The example below is an indication of what's required.

```
const isReady = new BehaviorSubject()

isReady.toPromise().then(console.log) // Want { state: 'value' }

isReady.next({ state: 'value' })
isReady.complete()

isReady.toPromise().then(console.log) // Want { state: 'value' }
```

EDIT:

looks like what I am looking for is 
Thanks @Akash

```
const isReady = new BehaviorSubject()
const onReady = isReady.toPromise().then(() => isReady.getValue())

onReady.then(console.log)

isReady.next({ state: 'value' })
isReady.complete()

onReady.then(console.log)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question? If it is **How to get previous/last value?**, you can look into `PairWise`

Comment: You can use getValue() to access the last emitted value of BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Updated with your solution

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `toPromise`?